# Update badge icon when app is in background/suspended mode

Tags: ios, ios8, push-notification, xcode6, apple-push-notifications

I want to update application badge icon when a notification is received. It works fine when app is running (active mode),but having trouble when trying to set it when app is in suspended/background mode. Want to achieve the same without using the  'badge' field in apns dictionary.

Here is what i am doing,

```
-(void) incrementOneBadge{
NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
numberOfBadges +=1;

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];

}

-(void) decrementOneBadge{ NSInteger numberOfBadges = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber;
numberOfBadges -=1;

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:numberOfBadges];
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
  if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {

  } 
  else {
    // Push Notification received in the background
    [self incrementOneBadge];

  }

  [self handlePushNotificationsForState:application withDictionary:userInfo];
}
```

Comment: You need to add badge info in push notification `Payload`, it will automatically increment in all state of application, you don't need to do it programatically.

Comment: @iphonic: I dont want to do it through Payload (want to handle it in the application, no logic on server).

Comment: then its not possible to handle in Suspend mode, other than push notification.

Comment: It is managed from server side to give badge icon, not from ios side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931484/application-badge-icon-not-updated-when-push-notification-arrives